# Role auto-assignment bot

Tags: python, discord.py

The bot does not issue a role when the user connects (there are no errors either)

code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

TOKEN = ''

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=int("680703508940455977"))
    await member.add_roles(role)
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Discord 1.5, you now need to pass in Intents. Everything is explained in the API docs ([link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)). In your case you need the `members` intent. Remember to also enable it on your bot's application page (as is explained in the link).

Without the `members` intent, `on_member_join()` will not activate.